# Generate rows based on division with remainder

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the best to generate rows based on division and remainer?

```
declare @Total int = 203;
declare @Batch int = 100;
```

I did some complicated query with T-SQL but it is not working.

Result should be:

```
100
100
3
```

Comment: Please, post your attempt.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have SQL2022 here's a way of building a recursive CTE and then using that data to build the result set:

```
DECLARE @Total INT = 305;
DECLARE @Batch INT = 100;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT @Batch AS Num, 1 AS x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CTE.Num + @Batch, CTE.x + 1 FROM CTE WHERE CTE.Num + @Batch < @Total
)
SELECT CTE.Num / CTE.x FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT @Total - MAX(CTE.Num)FROM CTE;
```

It initially builds the CTE in steps of @Batch but as a total (e.g. 100 then 200) up until the next iteration would take you over the total. I added a column to iterate by counts of 1 so that we can then later divide Num by x to get each value back to the Batch size.

Finally in the select there's a UNION to get the remainder which is the total minus the maximum value the CTE iterated to

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming* the latest version of SQL Server (2022 at the time of writing), as no indication of version has been given, one method would be to use `GENERATE_SERIES`. You can use this to generate one row per batch, and then return the modulo when the upper value is greater than than the total:

```sql
DECLARE @Total int = 203;
DECLARE @Batch int = 100;

SELECT CASE WHEN GS.[value] + @Batch <= @Total THEN @Batch
            ELSE @Total % @Batch
       END
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0,@Total,@Batch) GS;
```